# iOS/Swift: tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am experiencing a EXC_BREAKPOINT crash at line 389

```
386    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
387        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StationsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
388        cell.textLabel?.text = self.suggestionStations?[indexPath.row]
389        return cell
390    }
```

here is the crash report from Crashlytics, happening at 2% of users:

`Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Trenìt!                       0x10004a2e4 specialized MasterViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (MasterViewController.swift:389)
1  Trenìt!                       0x100046488 @objc MasterViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (MasterViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x18c6b239c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 544
3  UIKit                          0x18c6a6fc4 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2360
4  UIKit                          0x18c49cc60 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 172
5  UIKit                          0x18c3b9874 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 572
6  QuartzCore                     0x18bd11d58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 168
7  QuartzCore                     0x18bd0c944 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320`

any idea why this happens?

Comment: Cell might be `nil`. Did you check that?

Comment: Is there a human readable error message in the crash log?

Comment: @rmaddy that's the only crash log I can get, it's from Crashlytics

Comment: @ozgur, is it possible that the cell is sometimes nil and sometimes not? Considering the return value `UITableViewCell` is not optional, what can I do in case the cell is nil?

Comment: Is it possible that this code crashes always but only 2% of users use it? Like if it provides some rarely needed functionality?

Comment: @Avt I can go through that function and see that cell is not nil. I haven't been able to verify the condition when the cell is nil.

Comment: I found the bug, I wrote an answer for it.

Comment: Shouldn't the crashing line number be 388, if it was due to array not having element at that index. And the crash would have been array out of index. I have exactly same crash so finding reasons.
@DanieleB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crash was caused by the `suggestionStations` array not having a value at the index.

I was not calling `ReloadData()` on the table when the array was reset to 0. So the the table function was still called in a race condition when the value at the index didn't exist anymore.

The fix was to call ReloadData() also after resetting the array. Otherwise there could have been a check that the index was defined for the array, but this shouldn't be needed if reloadData is properly called each time.

Answer (score 1):

We have had the same issue. This issue is 100% percent reproducible on iOS 10 beta1.

Although hard to believe, we managed to fix the issue by giving a very short cell identifier on storyboard. Like "PhoneContactCell" rename to "PCell".

After some investigation, we kind of think it is a storyboard bug: if a cell prototype is copied and modified then it will probably have this issue.

Comment: We found the reason that lead to the crash. We used a 3rd party library called FoundationExtension, inside which overrided serval memeory management call in its NSObject category. We removed the library and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have definitely set your cell identifier to "StationsCell" in your `Main.Storyboard`. Select the Cell and go to the Attributes Inspector.

Also add `override` just before the function, so it should be `override func`.

Comment: If that wasn't set it would crash always, not just for 2% of the users.

Comment: This is a weird issue, Im getting the same, cant reproduce but some users are getting the app crashing on launch and its a EXC_Breakpoint. I did copy the tableview and prototype cell. Will recreate and push a build. Will comment back here if that fixes the issue.