# Tableview cellForRowAt crash even when I did reloadData after empty an Array?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have been searching on how to solve one of my biggest issues in my app, however my problem still exists even I follow this [iOS/Swift: tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671222/ios-swift-tableview-cellforrowatindexpath-crash). According to the link that I provided, always remember to reloadData after I empty an array. However, the problem still exists, and I don't know how to solve it.

Some logs on [Crashlytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yqdM.png) ...

My tableview cellForRowAt functions, and I did set cell identifier in my storyboard too.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Crashed somewhere here
    let currentRow = displayMainCell[indexPath.row] 

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? MainCell else { return UITableViewCell() } 


    if currentRow.id == "wotd" {
        cell.contentLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 22)
    } else {
        cell.contentLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 13)
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = currentRow.title
    cell.contentLabel.text = currentRow.content

    return cell
}
```

**ADDED:** I have problem with my didSelectRowAt also in different View Controller. Here is the implementation.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let currentRow = wordLists[indexPath.row]

    textField.text = currentRow

    let currentWordToSearch = currentRow.condenseWhitespace().lowercased()
    indicator.startAnimating()

    saveWordToHistory(currentWordToSearch)
    fetchWordFromDB(currentWordToSearch)
    wordChange(wordToEncode: currentWordToSearch, uuid: getDeviceID())

    wordLists = []
    tableView.reloadData()
    setupDatabase(suggWords: currentWordToSearch)
    tableView.isHidden = true

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: add your console log that would be better..

Comment: Are your displayMainCell and wordLists arrays nested? i.e [[String]]? and what are the types stored in these arrays?

Comment: @karthikeyan do u mean the error in console log? so far I didn't face any problems but my users did and I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: From where you're appending item to wordLists ?

Comment: @LouisLeung displayMainCell and wordLists are 2 different arrays and from 2 different ViewControllers. both are not nested. the types of the arrays are Object that store strings only.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar inside of a FMDB query. Do I need to add it to main thread when appending data into the array?

Comment: make sure wordLists isn't empty. Try guard !wordLists.isEmpty else { return }

Comment: Yes, you have to!

Comment: @VaibhavParmar I did put if-let before appending data into array. But I thought only UIKIT like update user's interface are allowed to be in main thread? updating data into array will cause any issues?

Comment: if yo've to reload the table view, then put else don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the following function doesn't return a constant value. it should be like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayName.count;
}
```

if you are already doing it. I would suggest you to try the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? MainCell else { return UITableViewCell() } 

if arrayName.count != 0 {
let currentRow = displayMainCell[indexPath.row] 

if currentRow.id == "wotd" {
    cell.contentLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 22)
} else {
    cell.contentLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 13)
}

cell.titleLabel.text = currentRow.title
cell.contentLabel.text = currentRow.content
}
return cell
}
```

Comment: So if the arrayName.count == 0 , cellForRowAt will still display empty cell and do nothing? will it still crashed? Btw, I added one more problem, but this time is for didSelectRowAt. the problem is the same. Should i put the arrayName.count != 0  after the let currentRow = wordLists[indexPath.row] ?

Comment: if you are using arrayName.count in numberOfRowsInSection and arrayName.count = 0, then cellForRowAtIndexPath will never be called.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are trying to access the element of the array of a particular index in which there is no element present.  
for your didSelectRowAt  problem your should put arrayName.count != 0 before the let currentRow = wordLists[indexPath.row] ?

Comment: Yea, I realised I did that mistake in numberOfRowsInSection and arrayName.count = 0. And now i changed, lets see how it goes. Yes you are right, I am trying access at particular index but there is no element present. I will update my codes and observe from there. Thanks. oh yeah, what happens when arrayName.count == 0 ? does the cell still appear and will it be crashed if user interact with ?

Comment: No if  arrayName.count == 0,  cellForRowAt will never be called. And there will be no cell displayed on your screen. so your application will run smoothly. But you need to get sure that you return arrayName.count innumberOfRowsInSection.